# In which version of Neo4j Community i can use point

Tags: neo4j

I found [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/spatial/#functions-point-cartesian-2d) that neo4j has a new spatial type `point` , i downloaded 4.1 and 3.3.5  community versions (*which are the latest versions*) and they both return this error

```
Neo.ClientError.Request.Invalid: Point is not yet supported as a return type in Bolt
```

in which version i can use point() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the **alpha pre-release 3.5.0 version** and it works

Answer (score 2):

It's available from the 3.4 series so you don't have to use the alpha pre-release version if you don't want to.